# exception information : Message: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: asp.net

I got an An item with the same key error when i load the page.Is there any solution to solve this ? Here's the error
General Information

```
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 

 MachineName: WIN-SKEC08HPAEB  FullName: InnoArk.APDMS.Common,
 Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null  AppDomainName:
 /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-130120289473554687  ThreadIdentity: innoark 

 1) Exception Information 
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  Exception Type: System.ArgumentException  Message: An item with the same key has
 already been added.  ParamName: NULL  Data:
 System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal  TargetSite: Void
 ThrowArgumentException(System.ExceptionResource)  HelpLink: NULL 
 Source: mscorlib 

 StackTrace Information 
 - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) 
 at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue
 value, Boolean add)  at
 System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) 
 at InnoArk.APDMS.WebApp.Controllers.SimulationController._List(Guid
 GroupId, Guid bcTempId, String[] id, String[] volumeAnn, String[]
 volumeAvg, String[] costAvg, String[] costAnn, String[] costIfAvg,
 String[] costIfAnn, Boolean isEditBC, Boolean isBC, Boolean
 isSimulate, Boolean isSave) in
 D:\dev\APDMS\Trunk\InnoArk.APDMS.WebApp\Controllers\SimulationController.cs:line
 2478
```

Sorry , Here's the code from SimulationController from line 2478 :

```
detailList = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    detailList.Add("id", entityId[j]);
                    detailList.Add("volAnn", volAnn[j]);
                    detailList.Add("volAvg", volAvg[j]);
                    detailList.Add("volLatestAnn", volLatestAnn[j]);
                    detailList.Add("volLatestAvg", volLatestAvg[j]);
                    detailList.Add("cAnn", cAnn[j]);
                    detailList.Add("cAvg", cAvg[j]);
                    detailList.Add("cIfAnn", cIfAnn[j]);
                    detailList.Add("cIfAvg", cIfAvg[j]);
                    detailList.Add("code", code[j]);
                    detailList.Add("isLatest", isLatest[j]);
                    detailList.Add("isDirty", isDirty[j]);
                    detailList.Add("curr", curr[j] == null ? "" : curr[j]);
                    detailList.Add("noOfOrder", noOfOrder[j]);
                    detailList.Add("isFilter", isFilter[j]);
                    tempList2.Add(entityId[j].ToString(), detailList); << line : 2478
```

Thanks for trying to answer my question ? :)

Comment: And what does line 2478 of `SimulationController.cs` look like? Perhaps post it and the surrounding lines?

Comment: Have you debugged, what are you getting in `entityId[j].ToString()`

Comment: Can you show how tempList2 is used? It sounds like it is stored in Tempdata.

Comment: Satpal@i've debug it but there's no error . Don't know why

Comment: Malcolm@tempList2 is a dictionary either

Comment: I had an issue where I had two variables named the same only different by casing in my post to the controller, description='value'  and Description='hello'. It seems that both are recognized by the model binder. I am not sure this is related since the only clue is asp.net .

Answer (score 3):

This means the dictionary named `tempList2` already has a key with the value in `entityId[j]`.

Looks like something is wrong with your loop, or `entityId` contains duplicate values.

Assuming it's the second option, use `.Distinct()`:

```
entityId = entityId.Distinct().ToList();
```

In case `entityId` is plain array and not generic list, have such code instead:

```
entityId = entityId.ToList().Distinct().ToArray();
```

Anyway to avoid a crash on those cases, you can add such validation:

```
if (tempList2.ContainsKey(entityId[j].ToString()))
{
    //already exists, you can show some alert here.
}
else
{
    tempList2.Add(entityId[j].ToString(), detailList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks . I follow the if condition but still the same . And how do i put 'entityId = entityId.Distinct().ToList() ? Thanks before :)

Comment: No, there's no way you still get same error message if you have that if condition. You copied something wrong. As for the line, just put it above the loop and the list will become distinct. (no duplicate values which cause the error you are getting)

Comment: i replace tempList2.Add(entityId[j].ToString(), detailList); with the if condition. Did i put the code in the wrong place ? and for the distinct , it show error which contain "cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'to 'string[]'"

Comment: Sorry, I gave you everything I could. If you can't understand how to use it I'm afraid there's nothing more I can do, I won't write the whole code for you. See my edit in case `entityId` is an array rather than a List but apart of that, really can't do anything more. Good luck.

Comment: Cheers, glad you were able to do that yourself. :)

Comment: i didn't read the error properly .. when i perform the if condition , the other line which has the same key error .. i thought the code is not working :)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are adding something into generic dictionary and you can not have duplicate keys there.

Before adding verify if it's already there.